# cannot apply operator '!' to operand of type 'string' in c# while trying to make a get request

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to build a website up and down checker. but when I try to run my program I get this error: (cannot apply operator '!' to operand of type 'string')

How can I fix it?

I'm new to c# btw.

the error is in the if statement.

this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace cc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Website for further checking: ");
            string url = Console.ReadLine();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
            Console.WriteLine("Checking...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
            Console.WriteLine("Found some shit.");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
            Console.WriteLine("Printing Request...");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string checksite = client.DownloadString(url);
            if (!checksite == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Bitch is Down!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @juharr i got this: error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'HttpStatusCode'

Comment: What do you really expect the response *body* to contain? It's not going to contain the response *status code*, so the comparison you're trying to do doesn't make sense. `WebClient` [should not be used in new development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks).

Comment: @madreflection what do you mean? I check if the request is not OK, print...

Comment: `DownloadString()` does not return an `HttpStatusCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `(!string == othervalue)` doesn't mean what you think it does. You're taking the negation of a string, which makes no sense, and then seeing if it's equal to the value on the other side, because `!` has higher [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170) than `==`.

But let's say you fix that: either `A != B` or `!(A == B)` would work. You still have a problem, because data types matter. It rarely makes sense to check the equality of two different kinds of object.

In this case, `DownloadString()` does not return an `HttpStatusCode` at all. It returns the body from whatever HttpResponse was provided by the page as a string, and **throws an exception** for anything that's not a good status code.

So you want this:

```
try
{
    client.DownloadString(url);
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your site is Down!");
}
```

Comment: when I try with google.com I keep getting your site is down! I'm sorry, but maybe did I missed anything? thanks.

Comment: Then you should check what you get in `ex.Message` to find out why the request failed. This is your job as the programmer: dig into what the data is doing at every step.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a string is not 'something' you have to add `()` like that:

```
!(checksite == HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

or

```
checksite != HttpStatusCode.OK
```

Comment: same error.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the != comparison.

Currently, you try to negate the string itself, which is not possible.

PS: I would change the outputs to something less offensive.

Comment: what do you mean? when I do != I'm getting: error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'HttpStatusCode'

Comment: @Xanward That is another mistake. You try to compare the downloaded text to a HttpStatusCode Enum value, which does not work.

Comment: See @madreflections' comment under your questions.

Comment: so how should I use !=?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve... Probably you want to check whether the string is not null nor empty?